# Change default document library

Tags: 2010, document-library, list-definition

Is there a way i can change the settings on the document library template?
There is a column we want to add as standard, so that it is there when they create it in the first place.

I am aware I can save it as a new template, but I want it to be available from the "New Document Library" option in the site actions menu.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have done a similar thing with a ListCreated event recevier together with a WebProvisioned event recevier.

These event receivers checks if it is a document library that has been created and i so changes the default content type and adds a field to the default view.

The Document Library template is located in the base.xml file **BUT if you make changes to this your solution is no longer in a supported state according to Microsoft** ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479188.aspx))

Comment: Thanks for this. A bit more customisation than I was after so I'll leave it for now but appreciate the response. Unless something else comes up I will mark this as the answer for you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding your column to the document content type?

Comment: Certainly could work, the difficulty would come if users didn't add it to content types  created later. Worth a thought though, thanks.